# ORM::factory is giving uncaught exception in Kohana

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

This is the error I am facing.

[image]

1. This is my controller code

   ```
   <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
   class Controller_Home extends Controller {        
        public function action_index()
        {
           $users = ORM::factory("users");
        }
   }
   ```
2. My model code

   ```
     <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');
     class Model_users extends ORM{ }
   ```

   I am on a tight schedule please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guess, that you have php7? Kohana work only on php5. Use https://github.com/koseven/koseven instead

Comment: I had done the same. I also added a comment here mentioning the solution, don't see why it ain't here anymore.